# Cucumber is not running my Step definition file (java)

Tags: java, selenium, junit, cucumber

When ever I run my Test Runner, cucumber generates a missing steps though i have implemented the steps in my Test_Steps class. I am able to navigate to the Test_Steps class from feature file using "find steps" in eclipse. Please help. Many Thanks

CucumberRunner:

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
    format = { "pretty","html: cucumber-html-reports",
               "json: cucumber-html-reports/cucumber.json" },
    features = {"src/features"},
    glue ={"src/features"}
)

public class CucumberRunner {

}
```

first.feature:

```
Feature: Login Action

  Scenario: Successful Login with Valid Credentials    
    Given User opened STM
    When User in LogIn Page
   Then Message displayed Login Successfully
```

Test_Steps (StepDefinition file):

```
public class Test_Steps {

    public WebDriver driver ;

    @Given("^User opened STM$")
    public void User_opened_STM() throws Throwable {
        // Express the Regexp above with the code you wish you had
        driver= new FirefoxDriver();
        //driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.get("http://10.100.2.127:9000/");
    }

    @When("^User in LogIn Page$")
    public void User_in_LogIn_Page() throws Throwable {
        // Express the Regexp above with the code you wish you had
        driver.findElement(By.id("input_login_password")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.id("input_login_username")).sendKeys("admin"); 
        driver.findElement(By.id("input_login_password")).sendKeys("");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/form/div[1]/div/div[2]/button")).click();
    }


    @Then("^Message displayed Login Successfully$")
    public void Message_displayed_Login_Successfully() throws Throwable {
        // Express the Regexp above with the code you wish you had
        System.out.println("Login Successfully");  
    }
```

Folder structure : All packages are under src folder

feature file :/src/features/first.feature
step definition file : /src/features/Test_Steps.java

console output:

```
Feature: Login Action

  Scenario: Successful Login with Valid Credentials [90m# first.feature:3[0m
    [33mGiven [0m[33mUser opened STM[0m
    [33mWhen [0m[33mUser in LogIn Page[0m
    [33mThen [0m[33mMessage displayed Login Successfully[0m

1 Scenarios ([33m1 undefined[0m)
3 Steps ([33m3 undefined[0m)
0m0.000s
```

You can implement missing steps with the snippets below:

```
@Given("^User opened STM$")
public void User_opened_STM() throws Throwable {
    // Express the Regexp above with the code you wish you had
    throw new PendingException();
}

@When("^User in LogIn Page$")
public void User_in_LogIn_Page() throws Throwable {
    // Express the Regexp above with the code you wish you had
    throw new PendingException();
}

@Then("^Message displayed Login Successfully$")
public void Message_displayed_Login_Successfully() throws Throwable {
    // Express the Regexp above with the code you wish you had
    throw new PendingException();
}
```

Comment: Can you show your directory structure? And the console output when you  run "CucumberRunner"?

Comment: updated the console output in my question

Answer (score 1):

The `@CucumberOptions#glue` property (poorly documented, I admit), should point to the **package** in which your steps are. Otherwise, Cucumber will look for steps in the same package as your `CucumberRunner` class.

Having said that, two remarks:

- make sure your classes are in a named package, not in the "default" aka. unnamed package. Just to make things easier
- make sure the Steps are actually compiled and on the classpath when you are running the `CucumberRunner`